# Python enumeration 1 and 0

Tags: python

can't make it and not flexible

i only can make it a number.Ex:input 3 show 000 001 010...

```
a=list('000')
c=''.join(a)
b=111
d=len(a)

while c!=str(b):
    chance=1
    for i in xrange(d-1,-1,-1):
        if(chance==1):
            if(a[i]=='0'):
                a[i]='1'
                chance=0
                print a
            if(a[i]=='1'):
                if(a[i-1]=='1'):
                    if(a[i-2=='0']):
                        a[i-2]='1'
                        a[i-1]='0'
                        a[i]='0'
                        chance=0
                        print a
                        break`
                else:
                    a[i]='0'
                    a[i-1]='1'
                    chance=0
                    print a
    c=''.join(a)
    print c
```

i need like input 1 show 0,1.input 2 show 00,01,10,11

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```py
import itertools

digits = '01'

nb_digits = int(input('How many digits each answer should have: '))

print(" ".join("".join(x) for x in itertools.product(digits, repeat=nb_digits)))
```

To understand it you would need to read on:

- Just a little bit of what is a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)?
- How to use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutation#itertools.product)
- What is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)
- How [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) can help you ask something to the user
- How to convert a string representing an integer number to simply an integer number using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)
- How to concatenate a list of strings using the [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method